# TinyMCE Javascript URL Question

Tags: javascript, urls, tinymce

```
ed.windowManager.open({
                file : url + '/shortcode_generator_popup.php',
```

I would like to move this file one folder above the current one that it's in. I'm wondering how I can rewrite this so that is points to the folder above. I've tried:
file : url + '../shortcode_generator_popup.php' but of course it only turns into:
/includes/js../shortcode_generator_popup.php

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use the [before_wp_tiny_mce()](http://wpseek.com/hook/before_wp_tiny_mce/) hook.  Then, you can define the url in PHP; and pass it to the page so it is available to TinyMCE.

```
function sgp_before_wp_tiny_mce() {

    ?>
    <script type="text/javscript">
        var sgp_plugin_url = "<?php echo plugins_url('shortcode_generator_popup.php', __FILE__); ?>";
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('before_wp_tiny_mce', 'sgp_before_wp_tiny_mce');
```

You may need to change the [plugins_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) to match the appropriate location of your php file.

Then, you can use the variable in your plugin tinymce script to get the location.

```
ed.windowManager.open({
    file : sgp_plugin_url,
```

I haven't tested this... it's from memory. Let me know if you encounter any issues and I'll adjust accordingly.